# Performing UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to kill my iOS app, running from background for that i used to do enable `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` in my info.plist file

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<true/>
```

But i am wondering, Is it possible to do it programmatically also, instead of changing info.plist ?

Comment: My first thought that comes to might is Why?? There should not be any reason to need to close your own app.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in the `applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method :

```
[[NSThread mainThread] exit]
```

**Warning** : Apple might reject you app if you kill it programmaticaly

Comment: Just be aware that the Apple review team might see this as an crash. Since you are not supposed to kill your app programmatically.

Comment: Yeah but with exit(0) this is the only way to kill you app. The plist flag is the best way. Updated my answer.